# Why do I get "ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1" when I try to clone github repo in Google Collab?

Tags: python-3.x, git, github, pip, google-colaboratory

I tried: `pip install git+https://github.com/adityatb/noise-reduction-using-rnn.git`
But I got the error:

```
Collecting git+https://github.com/adityatb/noise-reduction-using-rnn.git
Cloning https://github.com/adityatb/noise-reduction-using-rnn.git to /tmp/pip-req-build-ka8brgnj
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I tried to upgrade my `pip` and `setuptools` and got the corresponding console outputs:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (19.3.1)

Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (50.3.0)
```

But the error did not disappear. What's wrong with my commands or this repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is very simple: the repository just hasn't `setup.py` so *pip* can not install this repository. I need to copy repository files in my folder.